# Model change rendering in Backbone

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, view, model

Most Backbone tutorials and examples I've come across suggest something like this for your models:

```
this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
```

In my particular case, I'm creating a view for my model that is a `form`, and the fields are tied to model properties.  When the user updates a field on the `form`, the model should also be updated.  This has not been a problem, as I have events bound to the fields that fire off the appropriate code to update my model.

*However*, the problem I'm running across is that I also want the view to update when the model does (as in the above mentioned ubiquitous change event binding).  This is causing the view to re-render itself any time a field is updated, because the underlying model is changing.  So now any time I change a value on the `form`, my view is being redrawn.  This is both inefficient, and causing lots of frustrating bugs (like focus being lost).

How is this problem normally handled?

Comment: Don't render the view on the model change. Render it when you want it using `this.render`

Comment: @pvnarula: That would mean that my view would not update if the model changes via anything outside the view, though.  Are you suggested that that should never happen?

Comment: As an aside, the preferred way to listen for model changes in a view is `this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render)` as that will not leave a memory leak when the view is removed.

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks for that tip; I will update my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog

When you don't want your model change to trigger your view's rendering, use `{silent: true}`. As of the last version of Backbone, this will completely silence the change (it was previously just shut until the next non-silent change). So when the change to your model comes from some user input, use the `silent` flag.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to update a model without firing a change event event you can do so by calling,

```
this.model.set('val', newval, {silent:true});
```